# Executing Postgres statement or procedure without waiting for return

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, sql-function

I'd like to invoke some cleanup procedure after some INSERT is done, and the cleanup takes a long time. My sql client has very little tolerance on timeouts, so I'd like to return as soon as the command is issued.

I've tried Trigger --the INSERT triggers the stored procedure to do cleanup. The problem is that now the INSERT has to wait for the cleanup to finish in order to return.

I've tried calling a 'proxy' function which then calls the actual cleanup function, but it seems that the function call stack in Postgres is no different than in other languages. The client still waits for the cleanup.

What's the best practice in this scenario? Thanks!

Comment: Use `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` to run the cleanup as tasks from a helper daemon after commit.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use an external program to do this. PostgreSQL itself will not allow you to run things in the background. You may be able to handle this with [pgAgent](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/pgagent.html) or by creating your own program that runs constantly. You will need to send some kind of notification to the program, for which you can use e.g. a table with trigger on the insert, or listen/notify.